# Chromium debug build no TCMalloc symbols

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, chromium

I compiled Chromium as debug build

```
# Set build arguments here. See `gn help buildargs`.
enable_nacl=false
symbol_level=2
is_asan = true
is_lsan = false
is_debug = true
```

but somehow I cannot see TCMalloc symbols when using TCMalloc inspection script:

https://github.com/marcinguy/tcmalloc-inspector

With sample program compiled against TCMalloc it works.

In Chromium it cannot find these symbols:

```
# tcmalloc

pageheap_ = gdb.parse_and_eval('\'tcmalloc::Static::pageheap_\'')
central_cache_ = gdb.parse_and_eval('\'tcmalloc::Static::central_cache_\'')
thread_heaps_ = gdb.parse_and_eval('\'tcmalloc::ThreadCache::thread_heaps_\'')
sizemap_ = gdb.parse_and_eval('\'tcmalloc::Static::sizemap_\'') # XXX cache

spantype = gdb.lookup_type('tcmalloc::Span').pointer()

knumclasses = gdb.parse_and_eval('kNumClasses') # XXX skip 0?
kmaxpages = gdb.parse_and_eval('kMaxPages')
pagesize = 1 << int(gdb.parse_and_eval('kPageShift'))
```

How can I compile Chromium, TCMalloc used by Chromium with debug symbols, those symbols?

Thanks,

Comment: what platform are you compiling Chromium for?

Comment: You might have to explicitly instruct the build system to use `TCMalloc`. Pass this argument to your build command or modify `args.gn`: `use_allocator = "tcmalloc"`. I have not tried it because I don't want the whole thing to start compiling on my machine again

Comment: @Asesh for x86-64. Hmm actually thought tcmalloc ia default. It seem to be compiling by Ninja but symbols are not there. Looked for makefiles etc but cannot find anything. Will try yr suggestion

Comment: @Asesh tried it, ninja build system said nothing to so, so I guess it was already set

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/base/allocator/README.md#background tcmalloc is default on Linux. Confused what "none" will do

Comment: I guess with "none" it will use malloc

Comment: Added this to build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn ...   ´# Linux/Android/Fuchsia common flags setup.
  # ---------------------------------
  if (is_linux || is_chromeos || is_android || is_fuchsia) {
    asmflags += [ "-fPIC" ]
    cflags += [ "-g","-ggdb","-fPIC", ]
    ldflags += [ "-fPIC" ]
´ Now the flags seem to be there but is recompiling the whole thing

Comment: `Background` subtitle might be helpful to you: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/master/allocator/

Comment: Nahhh .. recompiled with use_allocator = "tcmalloc" and "-g","-ggdb" but the symbols are not there i.e kNumClasses, kMaxPages HOWEVER I can break on tc_malloc() in chromium, so it is there and is used